# How do I fill values for Somaliland in Plotly choropleth maps?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I'm making a choropleth map in Plotly Express.  My dataframe has a column called `'country'` filled with ISO 3166 3 character country codes, which serves as the location argument for the figure.

I can't work out how to give values for the area called Somaliland, since it lacks international recognition, and therefore an ISO 3166 code.

I'm refering to the grey area in the horn of Africa depected here:

[image: The grey area is what I'm referring to.]

What country code can I use for this?

Answer (score 2):

Plotly express default map only works with countries which have a ISO 3166 code.
In your case, you first need to download your own geojson file, e.g. from https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/. Then you can use other codes, e.g. `sov_a3` to refer to a specific country.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import json 
  
f = open('countries.json',) 
countries = json.load(f) 

data = data = [['ETH',112079000],['SOM',15400000],['SOL',3508180]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['sov_a3','population'])

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=countries, locations="sov_a3", featureidkey="properties.sov_a3", color="population")
fig.show()
```

Comment: It seems odd that they would choose a default map that simultaneous requires ISO 3166 codes, but includes a nation that doesn't have one.  Are you sure that's right?

Comment: In the documntation of Plotly you can read that they take the geometries from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/50m-admin-0-countries-2/ as-is. If you analysize this dataset you see that Somaliland is included but the ISO_A3 code is set to -99.